# How to select an item in a QListView that corresponds to the last inserted record of the underlying QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlistview

I am programming some kind of address book. On the left side of my application i have a QListView to display the names of my contacts. On the right side of my application i have a form to type in the information (e.g. name, address, phone number) of my contacts. I am storing the data of my contacts in a QSqlTableModel. I use my QListView to display one column of my QSqlTableModel.

My question is: How do I automatically select the item in my QListView that corresponds to the last inserted contact in my QSqlTableModel?

This is how I set up my model:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("datenbank.db");

model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable("demodaten");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setSort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
model->select();

view->setModel(model);
view->setModelColumn(0);
```

This is how I add a new record to my model:

```
QSqlRecord record = model->record();
for(int i = 0; i<record.count(); i++){
    record.setValue(i, "");
}

record.setValue("codenummer", p.getCodeNummer());
record.setValue("vorname", p.getVorname());
record.setValue("nachname", p.getNachname());
record.setValue("geburtsdatum", p.getGeburtsdatum());

model->insertRecord(-1, record);
model->submitAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can connect to the [rowsInserted](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal of your QSqlTableModel; it should be fired every time new rows are inserted into the model. In the corresponding slot select inserted rows using the listview's [selectionModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) method.

in your parent widget header define model and slot:

```
private:
    QSqlTableModel *_model;

private slots:
    void on_rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &source_parent, int start, int end);
```

connect to the model's rowsInserted signal in your widget constructor:

```
connect(_model, SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(on_rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)));
```

possible on_rowsInserted implementation:

```
void YourParentWidget::on_rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &source_parent, int start, int end)
{
    QModelIndex index = _model->index(start, 0);
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->clear();
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks a lot for your help! But unfortunately it doesn't work. Always the first item in my QListView is getting selected. What is weird beside of that is that on_rowsInserted() seems to get called twice when a new row is inserted in my QSqlTableModel. In the first call start is allways the index of the last item in my QListView. In the second call it is always 0.

Comment: "on_rowsInserted() seems to get called twice" doesn't sound right to me; I guess you would need to post up some of your code as root cause of your problem is in details of how you're initializing the model and how new rows are inserted

Comment: Hi Serge, I added some code. Maybe you now have an idea how to solve my problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From Qt Doc :

```
bool QSqlTableModel::insertRecord ( int row, const QSqlRecord & record )
Inserts the record after row. If row is negative, the record will be appended to
the end.
```

Are you ordering the table? The last inserted item, is not the last item of the table?

Get a presisten index with:

```
QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) 
int QAbstractItemModel::rowCount ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const
```

(column is not important if you have selectionmode Row )

```
QPersistentModelIndex ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

anter the insert but before the submitAll();

And select that row with (you dont have to use a selection model for this if you dont mind to change the current index)

```
void QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

It selects the item, too.

You can also scroll to make the new item visible:

```
void QAbstractItemView::scrollTo ( const QModelIndex & index, ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible )
```

Edited:
Don't know how i didsnt see the order before ....

Comment: Nvm, just saw you do order the model.
Cant you unset the order when adding and set it after the append?
Get a QPersistenModelIndex and do what i said before with it
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qpersistentmodelindex.html